# How do I stop the sync attempts for an app?

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications, itunes-store

Whenever I sync my iPhone with iTunes, the phone tells me:

> **iTunes Sync**
>
> 1 item could not be synced. See iTunes for more information.

And iTunes tells me:

> The app "The Elements" was not installed on the iPhone "[...]" because not enough free space was available.

This makes sense, because the app "The Elements" is very large. **But I don't want it on my iPhone anyway.**

How can I stop the attempted sync of this specific app?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to iTunes and select the device.

   [image]
2. Select the **Apps** tab.

   [image]
3. Press the **Will Install** button so that it removes the status and returns to an **Install** button.

   ## [image] <sup><sup>→</sup></sup> [image] <sup><sup>→</sup></sup> [image]
4. Press **Sync**.

   [image]

Comment: I tried that before. That is, I pressed the "Remove" button, which then became "Will remove". But the "Sync" and I got the same thing. However, I (only now) noticed that there was a (somewhat darkened?) icon for the app on the phone. I deleted it there and now things are OK. Thanks anyway (+1).